# Prove $\{x \mid d(f_n(x), f_m(x)) \le \varepsilon \text{ for all } n,m \ge N \}$ is closed

Tags: general-topology, continuity

In the proof of Theorem 48.5. in Munkres' Topology it is written :

> Given a positive integer $N$ and given $\epsilon>0$, define
> $$A_N(\epsilon)=\{ x; d(f_n(x),f_m(x)\le\epsilon\text{ for all } n,m>N.$$
> Note that $A_N(\epsilon)$ is closed in $X$. For the set of those $x$ for which $d(f_n(x),f_m(x)\le\epsilon$ is closed in $X$, by continuity of $f_n$ and $f_m$, and $A_N(\epsilon)$ is the intersection of these sets for all $n,m\ge N$.

I can understand the intersection of closed sets is closed, but it is closed for a single pair $n,m$ in the first place? I mean, why "the set of those $x$ for which $d(f_n(x), f_m(x)) \le \varepsilon$ is closed in $X$ by continuity of $f_n$ and $f_m$? I can understand that the set $\{x \mid d(f_n(x_0), f_n(x)) \le \varepsilon \text{ for some } n\}$ is closed in $X$ by continuity of $f_n$, but how it is for *two* functions and how it is for no fixed point $x_0$ such that the center of a closed ball to be defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $x\rightarrow  (f_n(x),f_m(x))$ is continuous from the continuity of $f_n$ and $f_m$.

Also $(x,y)\rightarrow d(x,y)$ is continuous in the product tolopogy, which is standard fact for metric spaces.

Therefore 
$$x\rightarrow (f_n(x),f_m(x))\rightarrow  d(f_n(x),f_m(x)),$$
is continuous. And then as you noticed $A_N(\epsilon)$ is closed as the intersection of closed sets.

Comment: Much better if you can identity those closed sets whose intersection is $A_N(\epsilon)$.

Comment: How $(x,y)→d(x,y)$ is continuous in product topology?

Comment: @L.G. we have the following inequality $ |  d(x,y) - d(z,w)   |\leq d(x,z)+d(y,w)$ so you get $ |  d(x_n,y_n) - d(x_0,y_0)   |\leq d(x_n,x_0)+d(y_n,y_0)$

Comment: And you can prove the first inequality by writing $ |  d(x,y) - d(z,w)   |\leq  |  d(x,y)-d(y,z)+d(y,z) - d(z,w)   |\leq  |  d(x,y)-d(y,z)|+|d(y,z) - d(z,w)   |$ and then using  $|  d(x,y)-d(y,z)|\leq d(x,z)$ and $|d(y,z) - d(z,w)   |\leq d(y,w)$

Comment: Call the final map $d_{n,m}$. Then we consider the intersections of $d_{n,m}^{-1}[[0,\varepsilon]$ which are inverse images of closed sets under a continuous map. @L.G.